# Removing column from database in Laravel 5+

Tags: laravel

I've a blog for which the `articles` table `Schema` is defined like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('thumb')->nullable();
        $table->text('excerpt');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->integer('comment_count')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->integer('view_count')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('articles');
}
```

I want to drop the columns `comment_count` and `view_count` without losing existing data in the table

I defined a new migration like this:

```
class RemoveCommentViewCount extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        //nothing here
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function($table) {
           $table->dropColumn('comment_count');
           $table->dropColumn('view_count');
       });
   }
}
```

and I did `php artisan migrate` . It did migrate successfully, but the two columns are not dropped.

What am I doing wrong? How can I drop those columns without losing the existing data in the table?

Comment: as pointed out by @Sangar82, i is  the `up()` method that is triggered when you run the `php artisan migrate`. The `down()` method is triggered in case you do a `migrate:refresh` or a `rollback` as explained below.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Your migration must look like this:

```
class RemoveCommentViewCount extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function($table) {
            $table->dropColumn('comment_count');
            $table->dropColumn('view_count');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function($table) {
            $table->integer('comment_count');
            $table->integer('view_count');
        });
    }
}
```

The dropColumn in the up method, because with new migration you want to delete this columns. If you make a rollback, you have another time the two columns

Comment: You may drop multiple columns from a table by passing an array of column names to the dropColumn method:
$table->dropColumn(['votes', 'avatar', 'location']);

Answer (score 17):

Even you can drop the multiple columns in a single line by passing the array column to `dropColumn` function.

```
class RemoveCommentViewCount extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function($table) {
            $table->dropColumn(['comment_count', 'view_count']);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function($table) {
            $table->integer('comment_count');
            $table->integer('view_count');
        });
    }
}
```

In case you have a **foreign key** constraint, then drop first the foreign key index association and then can pass the column to `dropColumn` function with others like following.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('customer_orders', function($table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['product_id']);
        $table->dropForeign(['shipping_address_id']);
        $table->dropColumn(['product_id', 'shipping_address_id', 'column1', 'column2']);
    });
}
```

Comment: upvote for pointing out foreign key constraint and that I don't have to type it manually :)

Answer (score 7):

Create remove column migration

```
 php artisan make:migration RemoveCommentViewCount
```

The `down` method is for rollbacks, so add dropColumn in your `up()` function and reverse in `down()`

```
<?php
  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class RemoveCommentViewCount extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        if (Schema::hasColumn('comment_count', 'view_count')){
  
            Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropColumn('comment_count');
                $table->dropColumn('view_count');

                //OR
                $table->dropColumn(['comment_count', 'view_count']);
            });
        }
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function($table) {
           $table->integer('comment_count');
           $table->integer('view_count');
       });

   }
}
```

Check laravel documentation on [dropping columns migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#dropping-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I edited the initial migration, that is the initial table schema, removed the columns and then run **php artisan migrate:refresh** and it worked for me

Answer (score -4):

Just add this code into your **down()** function in migration.php file

```
Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->integer('comment_count')->unsigned()->default(0);
   $table->integer('view_count')->unsigned()->default(0);
});
```

and then run --> **php artisan migrate:rollback**